# SVG&Css: label of marker path does not display in IE

Tags: angular, css, svg, ngx-graph

```
<svg:marker  id="markerSquare1" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="7" refX="4" refY="4"
orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5;">
  <svg:rect  x="1" y="1" width="45" height="45" [attr.fill]="node.options.color" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5;" />
<svg:text    id="markStart" x="1" y="5" font-family="Verdana" font-size="4" fill="red;" >{{label}}</svg:text>
</svg:marker>

 <svg:path
          class="line"
          stroke="#777"
          stroke-width="4"
          marker-start="url(#markerSquare1)"
        marker-end="url(#markerSquare)">
        </svg:path>
```

my problem is with the internet explore the label of the marker svg does not display as the picture below however with mozilla and chrome works well.

**with Internet explorer i get that**
[image: on IE]

**with chrome and mozilla i get that**
[image: with chrome and mozilla i get that]

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer does not render markers with `markerUnit="strokeWidth"` properly. It is a known bug that they never fixed.  It gets the scale wrong and draws the marker way to big.

The dark colour you are seeing is the text being drawn at a massive size.  The workaround is to use `markerUnit="userSpaceOnUse"`. And define your markers using userspace units, rather then relative to the line width.

PS. `position` and `z-index` are not valid SVG properties. They are doing nothing for you here.

Comment: even with markerUnit="userSpaceOnUse" I can not get the labels in IE because color of the <path> spreads in the maker, to run the strokwith on IE I did that:

var parent = p1.parentNode;
       parent.removeChild(p1);
       parent.appendChild(p1);

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and I will take another look.